# DbUnit and binary data

Tags: xml, unit-testing, dbunit

I use DbUnit for unit-testing of my DAO objects. It works great so far.

I have a problem, I have field ob type `byte[]` which is stored as BLOB  in the database. The column is not-null. How can I specify the value for this column in the XML dataset file, that DbUnit uses? The value can be nothing fancy, 5 bytes will be enough. I would like to avoid necessity to create extra binary files just for this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After all I solved it like that:

XML dataset file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    <!-- image_content is string '12345' Base64 encoded -->
    <IMAGE IMAGE_ID="1" IMAGE_CONTENT="MTIzNDU="/>
</dataset>
```

DbUnit has built-in support for Base64 encoded data, it transformes correctly into byte array.

Test case code:

```
assertEquals("12345".getBytes(), image.getContent());
```

Comment: This works with NDbUnit as well if you define it in your XML data file: `<HashedPassword>MjBxdxxY7NbME2Ha6DKhepVpwio=</HashedPassword>`

Comment: For example, base64 encoding in Postgres: `select encode('12345', 'base64');`

Comment: Just a heads up: when converting between strings and bytes and vica versa, such as in the assertEquals method example in this answer, always specify a charset to use. I just had a unit test that worked in my IDE (which defaulted to UTF-8) but failed when building with Maven (which used the windows default encoding, resulting in a string to not match)