# Using dbunit to pre-populate varbinary hex values

Tags: java, mysql, dbunit

I have a situation where I'm using a MySQL db, with a varbinary column which holds hexadecimal byte data.  I'm testing my application with dbunit, and I'd like to be able to pre-populate this column in my flat XML file, but I don't know how to encode a hex value that dbunit will understand.  Any help would be great!

Comment: You can encode the value in Base64. See the answer to a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107896/dbunit-and-binary-data). Using Base64 in DBUnit works for MySQL's blob, binary, and varbinary types.