# testing database with binary type in mysql using phpunit

Tags: php, mysql, phpunit

I try to write tests using php for database. I have a table that stores hash of password as binary.
How can I set test data in xml dataset, for example here is hex of my data and I get an error data too long to column.
Thank you.

```
 <dataset>
    <table name="subscription_ips">

     <column>password</column>   
     <row>
       <value>0x771C87E79B130E3FB966E424D7F1358D8DABBA0A26F288C0C1B5D8E3D95F2942100CA54B6824A7AC0964180A9426A1C37C371BA3FDBB000621FE175608C4B16C</value>
     </row>

 </table>

</dataset>
```

But it looks like phpunit can't insert it, using

`0x771C87E79B130E3FB966E424D7F1358D8DABBA0A26F288C0C1B5D8E3D95F2942100CA54B6824A7AC0964180A9426A1C37C371BA3FDBB000621FE175608C4B16C` instead of `0x771C87E79B130E3FB966E424D7F1358D8DABBA0A26F288C0C1B5D8E3D95F2942100CA54B6824A7AC0964180A9426A1C37C371BA3FDBB000621FE175608C4B16C`
 trying to insert test data to table.

Comment: what is datatype of password field? is it `BINARY`!!

Comment: binary just work as `char` as mentioned in mysql documentation. so your data will be truncated

Comment: it's password binary(64)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean, please?

Comment: Binary are stored as bytes. In phpmyadmin I can insert binay for example as: INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (0x771C87E79B130E3FB966E424D7F1358D8DABBA0A26F288C0C1B5D8E3D95F2942100CA54B6824A7AC0964180A9426A1C37C371BA3FDBB000621FE175608C4B16C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see now a decision like this, using replacement decorator:

```
public function getDataSet($pFileName=null)
{

    if ($pFileName===null) {
        $vFileName = $this->_fixturesDir.'init_flat.xml';
    } else {
        $vFileName = $pFileName;
    }


    $ds = $this->createFlatXmlDataSet($vFileName);
    $rds = new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_ReplacementDataSet($ds);
    $rds->addSubStrReplacement('##HASH_wince4_1318143535##', hash('sha512', 'wince4' . '1318143535', true));
    $rds->addFullReplacement('##NULL##', null);        
    return $rds;        
}
```

In flatXML:

It doesn't seem reliable, convinient and scalable. We try to replace some text with neccessary hash. I hope anybody could propose more appropriate decision of the problem.

Comment: You can always create your own version of the ReplacementDataSet decorator. I created a "HexadecimalAwareDataSet" decorator that does something like this but a bit more scalable.

Answer (score 2):

That's a literal binary string that MySQL understands. I suspect that PHPUnit doesn't understand it. You could try using the equivalent for XML using entity references or maybe you'll luck out and the parser PHPUnit uses supports [`base64Binary`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#base64Binary).

Comment: Could you please, explain what you suggest please? I'll take a look at the link.

Comment: I'm sory, I don't understand how you suggest to solve the problem.

Comment: If you're using DbUnit with PHPUnit, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107896/dbunit-and-binary-data/2108139#2108139) for an example. I am not familiar with DbUnit, but hopefully it will give you enough to go on.

Comment: Looking at [this blog post](http://digitalsandwich.com/archives/63-phpunit-database-extension-dbunit-port.html), it seems that the database extension in PHPUnit is a port of Java's DbUnit. Hopefully that means the base64 support is included.

Comment: There is a comment: This works with NDbUnit as well if you define it in your XML data file: <HashedPassword>MjBxdxxY7NbME2Ha6DKhepVpwio=</HashedPassword> in the answer link. It's not clear how in xml file, what tell that data are base64 and they should be converted to bytes by phpunit.

Comment: I added base64 in value tag and get error that too much length, I think it happends because phpunit process it as strings (and base64 inceasing the length) not conerting to bytes:<row>
<value>dxyH55sTDj+5ZuQk1/E1jY2rugom8ojAwbXY49lfKUIQDKVLaCSnrAlkGAqUJqHDfDcbo/27AAYh/hdWCMSxbA==</value> base64 here
  
   <value>1318143535</value>
   <value>0</value>   
   <value>2011-10-09 10:58:55</value>   

     <null />
     <null />    
   <value>0</value>      
   <value></value>   
   <value></value> 
   <value>1</value>     
   <value>c9de97978010bd1335891cc8a37eaf96</value>   

  </row>

Comment: I get an error data too long for column password, I don't know how to tell that data are base64.

Comment: I tried to this one and got the same error:    <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >dxyH55sTDj+5ZuQk1/E1jY2rugom8ojAwbXY49lfKUIQDKVLaCSnrAlkGAqUJqHDfDcbo/27AAYh/hdWCMSxbA==</value>

Comment: I suspect that PHPUnit's database extension doesn't have this feature. The other option is as I wrote above: use XML entity references to embed binary values directly. It won't be pretty, but it might work because it depends solely on the XML parser handling standard XML entities.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the idea about embedding binary data and how it could help. Could you please explain what you meant?